# Win32API/C++: Seleccionar un directorio y obtener una string con la ubicación.

Tags: c++, string, winapi

Tengo una aplicación en C++/Win32API/OpenCV la cual graba un video por medio de la webcam, y posteriormente lo guarda en una dirección en formato AVI. De momento, el directorio especificado está fijo mediante una String.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al iniciar el programa aparezca un cuadro de diálogo el cual permita al usuario seleccionar el directorio en el cual se almacenará el video. La ubicación de éste directorio entonces quiero pasarla a una cadena/string. ("C:/documents/vs2015/proyectos/miGrabador/aquivideos", por ejemplo).

¿Cómo puedo generar una ventana de diálogo de selección de directorios/folders y obtener una string con la ubicación del folder seleccionado (Para así enviarla de argumento de la función de grabar vídeo)?

Comment: Por lo específico de tu pregunta, asumo que vienes de otros OS, ¿ correcto ? Busca info sobre los `common dialogs` (dialogos comunes) de windows. Creo recordar que había uno para seleccionar rutas/archivos.

Answer (score 0):

La API de Windows cuenta con varios cuadros de dialogo que puedes usar para distintas tareas, como: seleccionar un color, seleccionar una fuente, abrir o guardar un archivo, en tu caso necesitas usar la función **GetSaveFileName()** la estructura OPENFILENAME se utiliza para configurar el cuadro de dialogo.

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
TCHAR szFile[MAX_PATH];

ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("All files(*.*)\0*.*\0");
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_SHOWHELP | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;

GetSaveFileName(&ofn);

// ofn.lpstrFile contiene el archivo seleccionado por el usuario  
// lo mostramos como titulo de la ventana
SetWindowTextW(hwnd, ofn.lpstrFile);
```